# Bash code to count size of files without folders

Tags: bash, count

count size of files in a specific directory but **without** the folders inside it

so if i have folder with

```
xxxxx.txt = 8kb
yyyy.exe = 29kb
game folder = 450kb
the answer will be 
37 kb
```

when i try to do `du -sh` it gives me the total size of file so thats not good

also can i control if output is in 'byte/mb' etc?

another quick question:
i want to calculate the number of folders and save it to a file and then once i run the script it will show how many folders were added or removed from last time

now my idea is to use the ls and 'wc' to count number of folders
and use tee command to output it to a file. 
but i'm having problem connecting everything together..

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
ls -l        |  # list file 
grep -v '^d' |  # skip directory
awk '{size+=$5} END {print size size/1024 size/(1024*1024)}' # sum size in byte and kByte, etc..
```

and

```
ls -l     |  # list file 
grep '^d' |  # select directory
wc -l        # count
```

both :

```
ls -l        |  # list file 
awk 'BEGIN{nbdir=0} /-/{sizefile+=$5} /^d/{nbdir+=1}END {print sizefile" bytes "nbdir" folders"}'
```

*awk : /pattern/{bloc}*

Answer (score 1):

A fairly easy way:

- Find only the files, only in the current directory, using `find`
- Pass the file list to `du -k` with `xargs`
- The `-k` flag of `du` produces result in kilobytes
- Use `awk` to compute and print the sum

Like this:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 du -k | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Using `ls`**

Here is a solution with `ls`

```
ls -l | awk '!/^d/ {sum+=$5} END {print sum}'
```

Result is in bytes. Pattern matches lines of all types except directories. For example to include only regular files we can use `/^-/`

from `man ls (1p)`:

```
   d       Directory.
   b       Block special file.
   c       Character special file.
   l (ell) Symbolic link.
   p       FIFO.
   −       Regular file.
```

---

**2. Using `du`**

you can get the total **estimated** disk usage (not always "size") of files excluding dirs with `du -Ssh`

> `-S`, `--separate-dirs`
>    for directories do not include size of subdirectories

with `-h`, this will calculate minimum one block (4K) for each file, because this is usually the minimum disk usage for the file system. `--apparent-size` can be used to print *estimated* actual sizes instead.

> `--apparent-size`
>    print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like

So `du -Ssh --apparent-size` (in human readable format) or `du -Ssb` in bytes, are *expected* to give same results.

---

In both cases, I notice that when using `-S`, there is an additional +4K (+4096) calculated for `.` the current directory. `-b` sets the counting block size to 1 byte, so I guess the file size estimation becomes accurate. So here is a way to extract the size (in bytes) of files in a directory, excluding subdirectories

```
du -Ssb | awk '{print $1-4096}'
```

note that only directories are excluded, so any other types like for example symbolic links will be included.